# How to retrieve the user name that is already authentified

Tags: single-sign-on, desktop-application, saml, cas

I have a desktop application that must work in an SSO environment (CAS/SMAL).
I just need to retrieve the already authentified user name. If the user is not already identified, I should consider that that the service is unavailable and fallback to another authentication mechanism.

Is this possible with CAS/SMAL ?

Answer (score 1):

CAS's SSO is generally limited to the boundary of the browser the SSO session started in. For example signing into CAS in Firefox won't sign you into CAS via IE or Chrome. You desktop solution is in effect a browser and has its own boundary.